# The text and other portion of my div section flowing out when changed from monitor to mobile view?

Tags: html, css, slider

I am trying to add a slider to my web App, after adding all the codes for the slider in a div section with class `slider`, when I change the view of the page from monitor or landscape to mobile view the text from the div section flows out of the section.
Here's my HTML code for the slider:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide|Monoton|Poiret+One|Raleway");

h1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-block-start: 0.67em;
  margin-block-end: 0.67em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h5 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 1px;
  font-style: italic;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.slider {
  height: 20vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #47d7ed;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.slider > ul {
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
.slider > ul > li {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 2000ms ease;
}
.slider > #input-slide-0:checked ~ ul > li.slide-0,
.slider > #input-slide-1:checked ~ ul > li.slide-1,
.slider > #input-slide-2:checked ~ ul > li.slide-2,
.slider > #input-slide-3:checked ~ ul > li.slide-3 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}
.slider > ul > li.slide-0 {
  background-color: #47d7ed;
}
.slider > ul > li.slide-1 {
  background-color: #47d7ed;
}
.slider > ul > li.slide-2 {
  background-color: #47d7ed;
}
.slider > ul > li.slide-3 {
  background-color: #47d7ed;
}
.slider > .slider-dot {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -4vw;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 300;
  font-size: 0;
}
.slider > .slider-dot > label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1vw 0.5vw;
  width: 1vw;
  height: 1vw;
  border-radius: 50%;

  background-color: #fff;
}
.slider > #input-slide-0:checked ~ .slider-dot > label.slide-0,
.slider > #input-slide-1:checked ~ .slider-dot > label.slide-1,
.slider > #input-slide-2:checked ~ .slider-dot > label.slide-2,
.slider > #input-slide-3:checked ~ .slider-dot > label.slide-3 {
  background-color: black;
}
.slider > .slider-dot > label:hover {
  background-color: #f73c3f !important;
}
.slider > .slide-description {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  top: calc(18% - 3vw);
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 200;
}

.slider > .slide-description > label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: default;

  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.75s ease;
}
.slider > #input-slide-0:checked ~ .slide-description > .slide-0,
.slider > #input-slide-1:checked ~ .slide-description > .slide-1,
.slider > #input-slide-2:checked ~ .slide-description > .slide-2,
.slider > #input-slide-3:checked ~ .slide-description > .slide-3 {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.slider > .slide-description > label > .text-slide {
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 6vw;
  top: 0px;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0%,
  100% {
      opacity: 0;
  }
  6%,
  25% {
      opacity: 1;
      z-index: 2;
  }
  30%,
  50% {
      opacity: 0;
      z-index: 2;
  }
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ ul > li.slide-0 {
  animation: slide 32000ms infinite -2000ms linear;
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ ul > li.slide-1 {
  animation: slide 32000ms infinite 6000ms linear;
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ ul > li.slide-2 {
  animation: slide 32000ms infinite 14000ms linear;
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ ul > li.slide-3 {
  animation: slide 32000ms infinite 22000ms linear;
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ ul > li {
  transition: none;
}

@keyframes arrow {
  0%,
  24% {
      z-index: 1;
  }
  25%,
  100% {
      z-index: -1;
  }
}

@keyframes dot {
  0%,
  24% {
      background-color: #333;
  }
  25%,
  100% {
      background: #fff;
  }
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ .slider-dot > label.slide-0 {
  animation: dot 32000ms infinite -2000ms;
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ .slider-dot > label.slide-1 {
  animation: dot 32000ms infinite 6000ms;
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ .slider-dot > label.slide-2 {
  animation: dot 32000ms infinite 14000ms;
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ .slider-dot > label.slide-3 {
  animation: dot 32000ms infinite 22000ms;
}

@keyframes description {
  0%,
  5% {
      opacity: 0;
      z-index: 2;
      visibility: visible;
  }
  6%,
  24% {
      opacity: 1;
      z-index: 2;
      visibility: visible;
  }
  25%,
  100% {
      opacity: 0;
      z-index: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
  }
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ .slide-description > .slide-0 {
  animation: description 32000ms infinite -2000ms ease;
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ .slide-description > .slide-1 {
  animation: description 32000ms infinite 6000ms ease;
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ .slide-description > .slide-2 {
  animation: description 32000ms infinite 14000ms ease;
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ .slide-description > .slide-3 {
  animation: description 32000ms infinite 22000ms ease;
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ .slide-description > label {
  transition: none;
}

.readmorebutton {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  padding: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #c10e0e;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;  
}
.readmorebutton:hover {
  color:rgb(149, 255, 0);
}
input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <input name="input-slider" id="input-slide-0" type="radio" class="input-slide input-slide-num" />
    <input name="input-slider" id="input-slide-1" type="radio" class="input-slide input-slide-num" />
    <input name="input-slider" id="input-slide-2" type="radio" class="input-slide input-slide-num" />
    <input name="input-slider" id="input-slide-3" type="radio" class="input-slide input-slide-num" />
    <input name="input-slider" id="input-slide-autoplay" type="radio" class="input-slide" checked />
    <ul>
        <li class="slide-0"></li>
        <li class="slide-1"></li>
        <li class="slide-2"></li>
        <li class="slide-3"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="slide-description">
        <label class="slide-0">
            <h1 class="text-slide">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
            <h5>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</h5>
            <a href="/" class="readmorebutton">Read More</a>
        </label>
        <label class="slide-1">
            <h1 class="text-slide">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
            <h5>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</h5>
            <a href="/" class="readmorebutton">Read More</a>
        </label>
        <label class="slide-2">
            <h1 class="text-slide">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
            <h5>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</h5>
            <a href="/" class="readmorebutton">Read More</a>
        </label>
        <label class="slide-3">
            <h1 class="text-slide">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
            <h5>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</h5>
            <a href="/" class="readmorebutton">Read More</a>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-dot">
        <label class="slide-0" for="input-slide-0"></label>
        <label class="slide-1" for="input-slide-1"></label>
        <label class="slide-2" for="input-slide-2"></label>
        <label class="slide-3" for="input-slide-3"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

when the page is in landscape mode it looks like this:-
[image]

Now, when I change the view mode to Mobile view, it turns out something like this:-
[image]
All of the text gets out of that div section and flows out everywhere, how can I stipulate that section of the code to display inside the same section only?

Answer (score 1):

change `height: 20vw;` to `height: 20vh;` to `.slider` class .. and add media query for a mobile screen and change it  `height: 100vh;`. and change the font size for `h5` to `font-size: 1em;` also for `h1`tage. as far as you need.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .slider {
   height: 100vh;
   font-size: 1em;
  }
  h5 {
     font-size: 1em;
 }
 h1 {
 font-size: 2em;
 }
}
```